# Gtk# works only on monodevelop

Tags: monodevelop, raspbian

I have monodevelop installed on Raspbian
i've created a program with Gtk#
in monodevelop it works great
however when i tried to compile it (mcs Program.cs)
i'm getting an error that says that: the type or namespace name Gtk could not be found are you missing assembly reference?

i've installed the  mono-devel,  mono-complete packges
i've installed libgtk2.0
still nothing help
how can i resolve this issue?

Comment: Compile it using msbuild/xbuild with the .sln/.csproj as inputs

Answer (score 0):

it was silly of me, but i forgot that there's a bin folder created after building in mono develop, there i can fine my exe and run it